# Android Radial Menu

Tags: android

I am looking for a implementation of a Radial Menu as in [here](http://phandroid.com/2014/03/16/google-patent-radial-menu-pie-navigation-android/). Can anyone help me where to get started? I cannot begin to figure out to draw one slice of a PIE. What can we draw this ?

Kind Regards

Comment: There is a stackoverflow post on this [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626887/android-radial-pie-menu

Comment: Can you give me pointers on HOW to move the radial with a touch ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that a similar thing was implemented in CyanogenMod roughly an year ago.
You can find the entire history for this task with links to the code here:
http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/34026/

The compete CyanogenMod soruce code is hosted at GitHub:
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/

The feature is based on the popular 'Pie Control' application.

Regards,
Vlad.