# Create a radial pie menu in Android

Tags: android, menu

Hello I want to ask how can i create something that looks like(aircommand) this:

[image]

I have made some search on radial pie menu but i could not find much. Is there anyone who can help me create this?

Comment: check this link: https://github.com/tapsandswipes/iphone-pie-menu

Comment: i am looking one for android

Comment: if you create that, you probable canot put in the an app and publish it in android market, i think that kind of "overlays" in menu are bloqued, only if your app is signed in the system you can create that kind of overflays. But if you are making that to rooted phones, it can work

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626887/android-radial-pie-menu
or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577200/radial-menu-android-with-button-click